# Extract Excel data by column name

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have an Excel data set:

```
"id","value","name"
  1  , 10,    "cat"
  2  , 20,    "fish"
```

In Python:

```
import xlrd

col1 = "id"
col2 = "value"
col3 = "name"
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("file.xls")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

result = sh.someMethod((col1,col3))?????
```

Is there a method that will return the columns by name?

```
print result
[[1,"cat"],[2,"fish"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

col_slice might be suitable, for example:

```
zip(sh.col_slice(0,1),sh.col_slice(2,1))
```

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm. It not exactly what I wanted, but I guess this is usable. I wanted something more in the line of separating columns by name.